# Python: How go to next statement when "Unsuccessful command:"occur

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have the following command of:

```
testing = plateX = g_o.getresults(g_o.Phases[0], g_o.ResultTypes.NodeToNodeAnchor.X, 'node')
```

it is not working in "Phases[0]" when it's 0 to 2 which gives the following error:,

```
plxscripting.plx_scripting_exceptions.PlxScriptingError: Unsuccessful command:
The command did not deliver any results
```

but will work from "Phases[3]" from 3 onward to whatever number it is. However in my script the x value in "Phases[x]" is different in every case, what i want is to test the x value until it worked without error...

So I'm guessing something like this:

```
for phase in g_o.Phases[0:]:
try:
    testing = plateX = g_o.getresults(phase, g_o.ResultTypes.NodeToNodeAnchor.X, 'node')
except ???:
    pass
```

but What should I put in the "???"? Or is there some other way to do this?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the type of error listed in the traceback. In the example error message you provided, this is a `PlxScriptingError`. So:

```
except PlxScriptingError:
```

Comment: i have tired so and it gives:

except PlxScriptingError:
NameError: name 'PlxScriptingError' is not defined @Bennett Brown

Comment: the full error is:
plxscripting.plx_scripting_exceptions.PlxScriptingError: Unsuccessful command:
The command did not deliver any results

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 48, in <module>
    except PlxScriptingError:
NameError: name 'PlxScriptingError' is not defined

Comment: The exception type must be imported, too. So either you put the full name: `except plxscripting.plx_scripting_exceptions.PlxScriptingError:`, or you do something like `from plxscripting.plx_scripting_exceptions import PlxScriptingError` first.